# How to create a character variable out of 2 others where the first word is upcase and the other in brackets in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have a table in sas and I want to create a new column C with a variable that should be computed by A and B, A should be in upcase letters and B in brackets.

If A is *dog* and B is *cat* then the C in that row should be *DOG (cat)*.

I' m very new to sas, how can I do that?
I know that I can get upcase by upcase(A), but I don't know how I can have 2 character variables after one another to create a new variable and how to put a new variable in brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS has a series of CAT.() functions that make that simple. CATS() strips the leading/trailing spaces from the values.  CATX() allows you specify a value to paste between the values.

```
 data want ;
   set have;
   length new $100 ;
   new=catx(' ',upcase(a),cats('[',b,']'));
 run;
```

Comment: PS If you actually wanted parenthesis, (), instead of the brackets,[], you mentioned in the problem statement then just change the text literals in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'm using cat/cats/catx only in very specific cases. For a problem like this, you can simply use the concatenate operator `||` that will make the code much more easier to understand:

```
data want;
  set have;
  attrib new format=$100.;
  new = strip(upcase(a)) || " (" || strip(b) || ")";
run;
```

OK, that's maybe a little bit more verbose, but I think that's also more easy to understand for a new SAS programmer :)